# Jquery window.location not redirecting but refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following Jquery snippet

```
// General search
$j(".search").each(function () {
    var baseURL = "/search.aspx?c=Entire%20Site&q=";
    var searchBox = $j(this);
    searchBox.find("input").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            submitSearchValueFromTextBox(searchBox, baseURL);
        }
    });
});



submitSearchValueFromTextBox = function(searchBox, baseURL) {
        window.location.href = baseURL + escape(searchBox.find("input").val());
    };
```

HTML for input

```
<span class="searchBox">
              <span>
                <input type="text" name="searchBoxHeader" id="searchBoxHeader" value="<%= SearchLabel %>" />
              </span>
            </span>
            <span class="searchBtn">
              <a href="#" class="btnSearchTop">
                <img src="/images/search_btn.gif" name="submitHeader" id="submitHeader"/>
              </a>
            </span>
```

What I am testing is when the user hits enter key to take the user to my search page, I find the code works correctly in that it finds the correct keyCode and when getting to the redirect function but it just refreshes the page rather than go to it.

Any ideas ?

Edit it works fine with onclick its the enter key stroke that doesnt work

```
    searchBox.find("a").click(function () {
        submitSearchValueFromTextBox(searchBox, baseURL);
    });
```

Comment: `alert(e.keyCode);` and see what value you get when you press enter. And check you console for errors!

Comment: E.keycode is correct and no console errors

Comment: Hm... try $('.searchBox') instead of $('.search')? Perhaps it's just a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the searchbox is present inside a `<form>` tag then hitting enter would submit the form. You need to prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: Hey, so yeah its inside a form. How can I prevent it from submitting ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the code right, your baseURL definition needs to either be inside the keypress() anonymous function, or it needs to be global.  You currently have it inside the each() anonymous function but outside the keypress() one, which scopes baseURL only for the anonymous function inside each() and therefore it's not accessible to the anonymous function inside keypress().

Comment: I tried even doing                 if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    window.location.href = "www.google.com";
                } but still just refreshes homepage

Comment: The keypress event handler should be able to "see" the variables defined in the parent closure.